# Render :json with includes does not render table data with different model name

Tags: json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I have following model structure

```
class SetBenchmark < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'benchmarks'
  has_many :my_question_sets
end

class MyQuestionSet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :set_benchmark, class_name: 'SetBenchmark',
end

class MyAdmin < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :my_question_sets
end
```

Following is controller render method

```
render json: my_admin, include: { my_question_sets: [ 'benchmark.*'] }
```

I am not getting `benchmark` data in response. Is it because it has different class name than table name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use association names, not table names in  json specification.

```
 render json: my_admin, include: { my_question_sets: :set_benchmark }
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Comment: How you will write it in the form of this

my_question_sets: ['organization, benchmark.*']

Comment: Why do you use `.*`? Could you send a link to description of this syntax?

Comment: I am also not aware of this type of syntax. Got it from somewhere. But I made changes as per your suggestions. It worked for me. Thanks